# GCP CLI SSO login fails when session monitored by Microsoft Cloud App Security

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, single-sign-on

We are have integrated Azure AD as identity provider from GCP cloud identities and also implemented real time monitoring and session control using Microsoft Cloud App Security (MCAS). From portal SSO login works fine and session monitored by MCAS.
When we are trying to login to GCP CLI using user account, it also does SSO login as expected through browser. However, during the login process, after providing credentials, authorization grant page for CLI is not coming up in the browser when session is monitored by MCAS (going via MCAS reverse proxy). It shows http 400 page in the [browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkthH.png).
When I stop session monitoring using Conditional Access policy in Azure AD, this issue doesn't occur.
Can you please let me know the issue or solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you share any log messages related to this issue? Do you have this issue with all of your accounts?

Comment: Yes, whenever we enable Conditional Access App Control using MCAS, we are seeing this issue for all users.

Comment: Please provide logs from GCP and Azure side.